# Unwanted space above section tag

Tags: html, css

There is an unwanted space at the top of the "Favorite Food" section in the web page I have created and styled for practice. The "section" elements should be inline-block. The problem came into being when I was attempting to center my unordered list. **How do I remove that space at the top of the "Favorite Food section"**?

```css
h1{
    background-color: #00F88F;
    color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

header{
    background-color: #00EEEE;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align: center;
}

section{
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

ul{
    display: table;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Introduction to HTML Submission</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <h1>Pratyay Mukherjee</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">One</a>
            <a href="http://www.coursera.org" target="_blank">Two</a>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Schumacher" target="_blank">Three</a>
            <a href="https://validator.w3.org/nu/" target="_blank">Validator</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <h2>Favorite Foods</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Pineapple</li>
            <li>Chicken Curry</li>
            <li>Fish Curry</li>
            <li>Meat Biriyani</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>Achievements</h2>
        <label for="m1">Progress in this course (100%)</label>
        <progress id="m1" value=100 max="100"> 100% </progress><br>
        <label for="m2">Progress in the Specializaton capstone (20%)</label>
        <progress id ="m2" value="20" max="100"> 20% </progress><br>
        <label for="m3"> Progress in life goals (33%)</label>
        <progress id="m3" value="33" max="100"> 33% </progress>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>More About Me</h2>
        <details>
            <summary>My Childhood</summary>
            <p>I was born in Kolkata, India on 20<sup>th</sup> Decemeber 1998. I loved to paint and play the piano since a very young age. I love the mountains and travelling</p>
        </details>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <img src="http://www.intro-webdesign.com/images/newlogo.png">
        This page was created by Pratyay Mukherjee and Colleen van Lent. To learn more about web design, visit <a href="http://intro-webdesign.com/">Intro to Web Design</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is around how `inline-block` elements vertically align. Add `vertical-align:top` to your section styling

```css
h1{
    background-color: #00F88F;
    color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

header{
    background-color: #00EEEE;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align: center;
}

section{
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:top;
}

ul{
    display: table;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Introduction to HTML Submission</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <h1>Pratyay Mukherjee</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">One</a>
            <a href="http://www.coursera.org" target="_blank">Two</a>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Schumacher" target="_blank">Three</a>
            <a href="https://validator.w3.org/nu/" target="_blank">Validator</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <h2>Favorite Foods</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Pineapple</li>
            <li>Chicken Curry</li>
            <li>Fish Curry</li>
            <li>Meat Biriyani</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>Achievements</h2>
        <label for="m1">Progress in this course (100%)</label>
        <progress id="m1" value=100 max="100"> 100% </progress><br>
        <label for="m2">Progress in the Specializaton capstone (20%)</label>
        <progress id ="m2" value="20" max="100"> 20% </progress><br>
        <label for="m3"> Progress in life goals (33%)</label>
        <progress id="m3" value="33" max="100"> 33% </progress>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>More About Me</h2>
        <details>
            <summary>My Childhood</summary>
            <p>I was born in Kolkata, India on 20<sup>th</sup> Decemeber 1998. I loved to paint and play the piano since a very young age. I love the mountains and travelling</p>
        </details>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <img src="http://www.intro-webdesign.com/images/newlogo.png">
        This page was created by Pratyay Mukherjee and Colleen van Lent. To learn more about web design, visit <a href="http://intro-webdesign.com/">Intro to Web Design</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was also going through other display options and used "table cell" for section display with a width of 30% while keeping the unordered list css intact. Is this a good solution semantic-wise?

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0 !important;` under `h1` in your css to remove the gap.

```css
h1{
    background-color: #00F88F;
    color: rgb(255,0,0);
    margin: 0 !important;
}

header{
    background-color: #00EEEE;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align: center;
}

section{
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

ul{
    display: table;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Introduction to HTML Submission</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <h1>Pratyay Mukherjee</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">One</a>
            <a href="http://www.coursera.org" target="_blank">Two</a>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Schumacher" target="_blank">Three</a>
            <a href="https://validator.w3.org/nu/" target="_blank">Validator</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <h2>Favorite Foods</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Pineapple</li>
            <li>Chicken Curry</li>
            <li>Fish Curry</li>
            <li>Meat Biriyani</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>Achievements</h2>
        <label for="m1">Progress in this course (100%)</label>
        <progress id="m1" value=100 max="100"> 100% </progress><br>
        <label for="m2">Progress in the Specializaton capstone (20%)</label>
        <progress id ="m2" value="20" max="100"> 20% </progress><br>
        <label for="m3"> Progress in life goals (33%)</label>
        <progress id="m3" value="33" max="100"> 33% </progress>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>More About Me</h2>
        <details>
            <summary>My Childhood</summary>
            <p>I was born in Kolkata, India on 20<sup>th</sup> Decemeber 1998. I loved to paint and play the piano since a very young age. I love the mountains and travelling</p>
        </details>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <img src="http://www.intro-webdesign.com/images/newlogo.png">
        This page was created by Pratyay Mukherjee and Colleen van Lent. To learn more about web design, visit <a href="http://intro-webdesign.com/">Intro to Web Design</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `!important` - [avoid it when you can](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used)

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1{
    background-color: #00F88F;
    color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

header{
    background-color: #00EEEE;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align: center;
}

section{
    text-align: center;
}

ul{
    display: table;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Introduction to HTML Submission</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <h1>Pratyay Mukherjee</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">One</a>
            <a href="http://www.coursera.org" target="_blank">Two</a>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Schumacher" target="_blank">Three</a>
            <a href="https://validator.w3.org/nu/" target="_blank">Validator</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section class="wrapper">
    <section>
        <h2>Favorite Foods</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Pineapple</li>
            <li>Chicken Curry</li>
            <li>Fish Curry</li>
            <li>Meat Biriyani</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>Achievements</h2>
        <label for="m1">Progress in this course (100%)</label>
        <progress id="m1" value=100 max="100"> 100% </progress><br>
        <label for="m2">Progress in the Specializaton capstone (20%)</label>
        <progress id ="m2" value="20" max="100"> 20% </progress><br>
        <label for="m3"> Progress in life goals (33%)</label>
        <progress id="m3" value="33" max="100"> 33% </progress>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>More About Me</h2>
        <details>
            <summary>My Childhood</summary>
            <p>I was born in Kolkata, India on 20<sup>th</sup> Decemeber 1998. I loved to paint and play the piano since a very young age. I love the mountains and travelling</p>
        </details>
    </section>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <img src="http://www.intro-webdesign.com/images/newlogo.png">
        This page was created by Pratyay Mukherjee and Colleen van Lent. To learn more about web design, visit <a href="http://intro-webdesign.com/">Intro to Web Design</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

you can use flex